# How to isolate elements in a 2-element array returned from a function?

Tags: php, arrays, function, multiple-return-values

I am using a PHP function that will return 2 arrays. Below is my function:

```
function imserv($id){
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("feed.xml");
    $images = $xml->xpath('//IMAGE');
    $services=$xml->xpath('//SERVICES');

    return array ($images,$services);
}
```

I use the below code to get results from the services block:

```
$services = imgserv('5874');

foreach ($services as $servicerow)
{   
    var_dump($servicerow);
}
```

The problem is that when it try to get only the values of the services, it returns both, services and images together. I need to to use both in two different places so how do I separate it to be used differently?

Below is my feed XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<FOUND>
<NFO>
<IMAGES>
    <IMAGE>
      <SMALL>images/small.jpg</SMALL> 
      <MED>images/med.jpg</MED> 
      <LARGE>images/large.jpg</LARGE> 
      <EXTRAL>images/extra.jpg</EXTRAL> 
    </IMAGE>
    <IMAGE>
      <SMALL>images1/small.jpg</SMALL> 
      <MED>images1/med.jpg </MED> 
      <LARGE>images1/large.jpg</LARGE> 
      <EXTRAL>images1/extra.jpg</EXTRAL> 
    </IMAGE>
    <IMAGE>
      <SMALL>images2/small.jpg</SMALL> 
      <MED>images2/med.jpg </MED> 
      <LARGE>images2/large.jpg</LARGE> 
      <EXTRAL>images2/extra.jpg</EXTRAL> 
      </IMAGE>
   </IMAGES>

<SERVICES>
<GROUP><GROUPNAME>Officials</GROUPNAME><SERVICE>
<TYPE>Handy</TYPE>
<NB>0</NB>
</SERVICE>
<SERVICE>
<TYPE>Bedroom</TYPE>
<NB>0</NB>
</SERVICE>
<SERVICE>
<TYPE>Meeting Rooms</TYPE>

<NB>0</NB>
</SERVICE>
<SERVICE>
<TYPE>Conferencing</TYPE>
<NB>0</NB>
</SERVICE>
<SERVICE>
<TYPE>Offices</TYPE>
<NB>0</NB>
</SERVICE>
</GROUP>
<GROUP><GROUPNAME>Reception</GROUPNAME><SERVICE>

<TYPE>Support</TYPE>
<NB>0</NB>
</SERVICE>
<SERVICE>
<TYPE>Reception</TYPE>
<NB>0</NB>
</SERVICE>
<SERVICE>
<TYPE>Telephone</TYPE>
<NB>0</NB>
</SERVICE>

</GROUP>
<GROUP><GROUPNAME>Authent</GROUPNAME><SERVICE>
<TYPE>Cams</TYPE>
<NB>0</NB>
</SERVICE>
</GROUP>
<GROUP><GROUPNAME>IT</GROUPNAME><SERVICE>
<TYPE>Internet</TYPE>
<NB>0</NB>
</SERVICE>
<SERVICE>
<TYPE>Telephone System</TYPE>

<NB>0</NB>
</SERVICE>
</GROUP>
<GROUP><GROUPNAME>Amenities</GROUPNAME>
<SERVICE>
<TYPE>24/7</TYPE>
<NB>0</NB>
</SERVICE>
<SERVICE>
<TYPE>AC</TYPE>
<NB>0</NB>
</SERVICE>

</GROUP>
</SERVICES>
</NFO>
</FOUND>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier if You change function to something like this:

```
function imserv($id){
$a = array();
$xml=simplexml_load_file("feed.xml");

$a['images']=$xml->xpath('//IMAGE');
$a['services']=$xml->xpath('//SERVICES');

return $a;
}
```

Then You will be able to write something like this

```
$imservarr=imgserv('5874');
foreach ($imservarr['services'] as $servicerow)
{   
var_dump($servicerow);    
}
foreach ($imservarr['images'] as $imagerow)
{   
var_dump($imagerow);    
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This will do the trick:

```
list($images, $services) = imgserv('5874');
```

Answer (score 0):

Constructing your function's returned data as an indexed array will make it easier to unpack in the calling script.  In modern PHP, `list()` is replaced with "array destructuring" syntax. Or you can just access an element by its index. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/ZunMJ)

```
function imgserv(int $id): array
{
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("feed.xml");
    return [
        $xml->xpath('//IMAGE'),
        $xml->xpath('//SERVICES'),
    ];
}

[$images, $services] = imgserv('5874');
var_export($services);
// or var_export(imgserv('5874')[1]);
```

---

Alternatively, returning an associative array will be much easier to understand.

```
return [
    'images' = $xml->xpath('//IMAGE'),
    'services' = $xml->xpath('//SERVICES'),
];
```

Then you access `var_export(imgserv('5874')['services]);`

---

Ultimately, we need to discuss the smelly elephant in the room.  It seems your application is defying the rule of single-responsibility.  When a function is doing too many things, a symptom is needing to return an array of data which doesn't need to be associated as an array.

To refactor, pull the separate processes into their own function. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/M30LD)

```
function parseFeedById($id)
{
    return simplexml_load_file("feed.xml");
}

function getImagesFromXML($xml)
{
    return $xml->xpath('//IMAGE');
}

function getServicesFromXML($xml)
{
    return $xml->xpath('//SERVICES');
}

var_export(getServicesFromXML(parseFeedById('5874')));
```